# SSH unstable after upgrade to 20.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, ssh

I did the feature upgrade to 20.04 LTS from 18.04 LTS server.

Now my SSH is unstable i have uninstalled the package and reinstalled using the maintainers config for all the files it requested.

I can connect without issue but after about 30secs i lose connection on Putty and my guacamole SSH connections.

When looking at the logs i see no errors just my user password getting accepted and the session opening.

It is not timing out from inactivity spaming *ls* it still losses connection, I have the added the TCPKeepAlive, KeepAlive and ClientAliveInterval

I have been able to SSH from cmd and get debug and got the following

```
debug2: channel 0: request window-change confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: client_check_window_change: changed
debug2: channel 0: request window-change confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: recv - from CB ERROR:10060, io:000002531D8A55D0
debug3: send packet: type 1
debug3: send - WSASend() ERROR:10054, io:000002531D8A55D0
Connection reset by xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22
```

Comment: Is this happening more than one particular  host?

Comment: no, can ssh to my vm on my pc running the 20.04 aswell and my router

Comment: So your newly updated 20.04 server is dropping connections made from whatever client requests connection? Or when you try to connect FROM your new 20.04 server machine the remote server (VM or router) drops your connection?

Comment: server is updated to 20.04 connection from my PC on windows is unable to connect to it without it dropping a continuous ping suggests that it is not with the network. SSH from the server to my test VM on my pc is fine

Comment: So i am going to close this as i have no idea what changed but no drops anymore, no updates either and its been on and has an uptime of 5 days

Comment: Ack. Those darn gremlins.